# Image of Homomorphism of Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

This is exercise from Lee: Introduction to smooth manifolds.

Suppose $f \colon G \to H$ is homomorphism of Lie groups (real, finite-dimensional).

**Q: Is image $Im(f) \subseteq H$ a Lie subgroup of H?**

That is, is there topology and smooth structure on $Im(f)$ such that inclusion $Im(f) \hookrightarrow H$ is immersion, and such that induced operation $Im(f) \times Im(f) \hookrightarrow H \times H \to Im(f) \subseteq H$ is smooth.

The author of [these notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~womp/2007/lie2007.pdf) says (last paragraph on the first page) that the answer is no, provides counterexample (dense line on torus), but the proof is ommited. Is it correct?

I need positive proof of that, to understand the following characterisation: Lie group admits faithfull finite-dimensional representation if and only if it is (isomorphic to) Lie subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.

One more thing. It is easy to see that $Ker(f)$ is Lie subgroup of $G$ using nontrivial [Closed subgroup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_theorem). Is there more direct proof?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how you define *Lie subgroups*. I may be wrong, but if I remember correctly, Lee defines a Lie subgroup to be a sub-object in both, the manifold- and the group- sense, and that they still are compatible. If so, the given counterexample works: the dense line on the torus is not a submanifold. Another common definition doesn't require this and then, the answer to the question would be yes (almost by definition).

Comment: I am using definition which says that Lie subgroup is immersed submanifold (so not necesseraly with subspace topology).

Comment: So it is really not clear to me how tu put topology and smooth structure on $Im(f)$ so that everything works out.

Comment: Give $G/\ker(f)$ the induced Lie group structure (this requires that you know that the kernel is a closed normal subgroup) and use the natural group isomorphism from $G/\ker(f)$ to the image of $f$ to define a differentiable structure on it. W.r.t. this, the inclusion into $H$ is nothing but $f$ (modulo kernel) and hence is smooth. The multiplication should be smooth since $f$ was a morphism of lie groups. (I didn't check that!) As the inclusion then is an injective Lie group homomorphism, it automatically is an immersion.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. At first, I thought that I must work the coordinate charts explicitely. I got the smoothness of multiplicaion myself. And for the kernel part, I can show that Lie group homomorphism must be of constant rank, and that means that level sets are embedded submanifolds of domain, and therefore closed. I still have to work out the quotienting of manifolds, but I know where to look now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f\colon G\to H$ be a homomorphism of Lie groups as in the question. Via the natural group isomorphism, we can consider $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}\im(f)$ as $G/\ker(f)$. Since $\ker(f)\subset G$ is a closed subgroup, $G/\ker(f)$ has a canonical Lie group structure. Using this to impose a Lie group structure on $\im(f)$, it becomes a Lie subgroup of $H$.

We may clarify this, by showing that the given definition of Lie subgroups coincides with the following: A subset $I\subset H$ of a Lie group $H$ is an (immersed) Lie subgroup, if there exists a Lie group $I'$ and an injective homomorphism of Lie groups $I'\to H$, such that $\im(I'\to H) = I$.

Suppose this for the moment. Then the induced Lie group homomorphism $\bar{f}\colon I' := G/\ker(f)\hookrightarrow H$ has the same image as $f$ and is injective by construction. Thus $\im(f)$ is an immersed Lie subgroup of $H$.

To show the equivalence of the definitions, everything is tautological, except the fact that injective Lie group homomorphisms are automatically immersions. Actually, I didn't knew the way you are describing to see this in your comment below your question; I'm used to reduce the question to the unit and then argue via the exponential map, which is a local diffeomorphism. Indeed, it suffices to show that the derivative of $\iota\colon I'\to H$ is injective at the unit $e$. But the exponential maps $\exp_{I'}\colon T_e I'\to I'$ and $\exp_{H}\colon T_e H\to H$ are local diffeomorphisms at $0$, and since we have a commutative square $\exp_{H}\circ d\iota = \iota\circ\exp_{I'}$, the injectivity of $d\iota$ at $e$ follows from the injectivity of $\iota$.

Comment: Thanks. For your last paragraph, I can show that Lie group homomorphism has constant rank, and that injective map with constant rank must be an immersion (these facts are propositions in Lee's book).